# ninguém não ligou X ninguém ligou!

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, diferenças

Qual é a diferença entre ***ninguém não ligou*** e ***ninguém ligou***?

Os dois são corretos e podem ser usados em frases diferentes?

Por exemplo qual é a diferença entre esses dois casos?

> Ninguém não ligou enquanto estive fora?
>
> Ninguém ligou enquanto estive fora?

Comment: Eu nunca ouvi "Ninguém não ligou". Essa frase ficaria algo como em inglês: "Nobody did not call". Que o correto seria Nobody called. Isso quer dizer que quando usas "Ninguém" não precisa usar a frase no negativo.

Comment: Obrigada pela explocação. Mais por que **Não há ningúem nos esperando** está correto?

Comment: @Majid, opinião sem fundamento em relação a se "não há ninguém nos esperando" está correto: acho que sim, mas também acho que há controvérsias. Mas não confies em mim: esta é uma opinião sem fundamento.

Comment: _Ninguém não ligou_ era gramatical no português antigo, mas já não o é. Para mais informação podes ver [aqui](https://web.archive.org/web/20160609065044/http://www.apl.org.pt/docs/actas-12-encontro-apl-1996_vol2.pdf) a partir da página 183 do pdf (Aspectos da negação na história das línguas românicas (Da natureza de palavras como _nenhum_, _nada_, _ninguém_) de Ana Maria Martins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não se diz **ninguém não* (o asterisco, *, indica construção errada). Há duas maneira de fazer a tua pergunta:

> **Ninguém** ligou enquanto estive fora?
>
> **Não** ligou **ninguém** enquanto estive fora?

Mas é errado dizer ****ninguém não** ligou enquanto estive fora?* Ou seja, se começamos a frase com *não*, temos de acrescentar *ninguém* depois do verbo (se não, não se saberia de quem estávamos a falar); mas se começamos a frase com *ninguém*, já não podemos acrescentar um *não*.

Passa-se o mesmo com ***nada, nenhum e nunca*:**

> **Não** se passou **nada**
> **Nada** se passou
> [Errado:] ***Nada não** se passou

> **Não** entrou aqui **nenhum** gato
> **Não** entrou aqui gato **nenhum**
> **Nenhum** gato entrou aqui
> [Errado:] ***Nenhum** gato **não** entrou aqui

> **Não** fui **nunca** à China
> **Nunca** fui à China
> [Errado:] ***Nunca não** fui à China

---

Encontrei uma explicação engraçada neste [*Estudos de Língua Portuguesa* de José Augusto de Carvalho](https://books.google.pt/books?id=F3aMDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT120&dq=%22ningu%C3%A9m%20n%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjX6PDx4e_rAhW9D2MBHVwLBuIQ6AEwA3oECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ningu%C3%A9m%20n%C3%A3o%22&f=false), a propósito do *ninguém*. Diz ele que se começarmos a oração negativa com *não*, precisamos de acrescentar um sujeito depois do verbo: “não saiu José” ou “não saiu ninguém”, em que *José* e *ninguém* são os sujeitos das orações. Mas se começarmos a oração com o sujeito, fica “José não saiu”, mas simplesmente “ninguém saiu”, porque o sujeito *ninguém* já nega a oração.

Não me parece que isto seja uma explicação completa, mas pereceu-me engraçada. É preciso acrescentar que em muitas línguas não são possíveis duas negações numa oração. Por exemplo, no inglês padrão, é errado **I didn’t see nobody*; tem de ser *I didn’t see anybody*. Mas no português é ao contrário: não pode ser **não vi alguém*; tem de ser *não vi ninguém*. A segunda palavra tem de concordar com o *não*. Chama-se a isto *concordância negativa*.

Comment: Perfeito e muito obrigado pelo resposto e explicações!